# Multi tenant Isolated DB structure with ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, multi-tenant, saas

I am working on creating the multi-tenant SaaS application using MVC 5. Based on the MSDN documents, I created the Apps and successfully completed the Auth process. But the sample comes with EntityFramework. But I need to get the tenant connection string from the master DB and dynamically establish tenant DBconnection in the application based on the host url (I have WEB API which connects the ADO Project). I don't want to go to EF and purely achieve it using ADO.NET
I am looking into the many solutions. But not satisfactory (I need to retain the tenant connection string for all the calls. Not sure if Session is the best option.

My Sample CODE:
**Step 1:**
After successful login.

```
public  SqlConnection CreateTenantConnectionDatabase(string tenant)
    {
        string databaseServer = "";
        string database = "";
        string username = "";
        string password = "";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MasterDBConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "USP_GetTenantDBDetails";
```

**Step 2:**
Dynamically Form the tenant connection string will be used in each DB call

```
private static string GetTenantConnectionString(string databaseServer, string database, string username, string password)
    {
         //form the tenant connection string dynamically
    }
```

**Step 3**
My repository class

```
 public TenantDTO GetTenantDetails(string TenantName)
    {
        TenantDTO tenantDTO = new TenantDTO();
        using (var dbConnection = applicationRepository.CreateTenantConnectionDatabase(TenantName))
        {
            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
```

Comment: Did you try shard map from Microsoft Azure, works for non azure db sharding as well

Comment: I thought sharding is for multi tenants sharing the same database. In my scenario, i have multiple DBs (DB per tenant). can you post some sample code

Comment: Refer the samples given here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Elastic-Scale-with-Azure-bae904ba?SRC=VSIDE. This works perfectly fine for your use case.